# Inline editing headers

Tags: jquery, html, events

Basically, what I need is a standard header on a page, and once clicked, it "turns" into an input[type="text"] or rather toggles the related input field. As you type in the input field, the value should replace the text of the header, and the tab key should also work, so if I'm in focus on the first field, or second field and press "Shift tab"it will hide the correct fields.

Here's my html markup

```
<div class="stepInformation" title="Click to edit">
      <h4 class="blue nameEdit">Enter Order Name</h4> 
      <input type="text" id="orderName" value="" placeholder="Enter Order Name"
            style="display:none">
      <h4 class="blue descriptionEdit">Enter Order Description</h4> 
      <input type="text" id="orderDescription" value="" placeholder="Enter Order Description"
            style="display:none">
</div>
```

Comment: look at [jEditable plugin](http://www.appelsiini.net/projects/jeditable)

Answer (score 0):

Hope that works..

```
$('.stepInformation h4').click(function(){$('.stepInformation input').hide();$(this).next('input').fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).focus()})});
$('.stepInformation input').keydown(function(e) {
  var keyCode = e.keyCode || e.which;
  if(keyCode == 9) {
    e.preventDefault()
    if(e.shiftKey) {
    $(this).parent().find(':input').fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).focus()});
    }
    else {
    $(this).nextAll(':input:first').fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).focus()});
    }
    $(this).hide()
  }
});
$('.stepInformation input').keyup(function(){
  $(this).prevAll('h4:first').text($(this).val());
});
```

This is to hide the headers, but I wouldn't use it:

```
$('.stepInformation input').on('focus',function(){
    $('.stepInformation h4').show();
    $(this).prevAll('h4:first').hide();
});
```

PS. I got some problem using **.show().focus()**, that's why I used **.fadeIn(100,function(){$(this).focus()})**